# send reports to remote sonar from dev@cloud jenkins through an ssh tunnel

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, cloudbees

i have a sonar running that uses a mysql database. i want to send reports to this sonar from my cloudbees dev@cloud jenkins.

as far as i understand the sonar plugin and sonar in general jenkins creates reports and inserts them directly into the sonar database.

my problem is that my database is not open to the internet. if i want to connect to it from somewhere else i need to go through an ssh gateway.

is it possible to configure the cloudbees jenkins to connect to the mysql database through the gateway?

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to internal resources from DEV@Cloud jenkins using a [VPN](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/JenkinsVPN).
This is still in beta, but will cover your use case.
Other option is to use hosted sonar on cloudbees.

Answer (score 0):

SSH tunnelling is the way to do this:

- http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/access-your-mysql-server-remotely-over-ssh/

Sonar should not require any special adaptation, apart from connecting to localhost

Couple of issues with this approach:

- I don't use cloudbees, so don't know if you have the required access for setup of an ssh tunnel.
- Performance... Sonar uses JDBC to talk to it's database and is very chatty. Even without SSH expect to see a serious degradation in the amount of time it takes to complete the Sonar step